# Failed to launch chaincode spec(Error starting container: cannot connect to Docker endpoint)"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I was trying to query transaction using the following command and see the following error

```
peer chaincode query -n <chaincodeId> -c '{"Function": "query", "Args": ["a"]}' -u jim

23:52:59.542 [crypto] main -> INFO 001 Log level recognized 'info', set to INFO
Usage:
peer chaincode query [flags]

Flags:
-x, --hex[=false]: If true, output the query value byte array in hexadecimal. Incompatible with --raw
-r, --raw[=false]: If true, output the query value as raw bytes, otherwise format as a printable string

Global Flags:
-c, --ctor="{}": Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format
-l, --lang="golang": Language the chaincode is written in
--logging-level="": Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
-n, --name="": Name of the chaincode returned by the deploy transaction
-p, --path="": Path to chaincode
-u, --username="": Username for chaincode operations when security is enabled
```

Error: Error querying chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Error starting container: cannot connect to Docker endpoint)"

I'm running peer in NON-DEV mode (mode: net). In net mode, validator will run chaincode in docker container.

Brief summary of peer node log

23:14:57.568 [devops] invokeOrQuery -> DEBU 03c Initializing secure devops using context jim
23:14:57.568 [crypto] invokeOrQuery -> INFO 03d Initializing client [jim]...
23:14:57.682 [crypto] invokeOrQuery -> INFO 03e Initializing client [jim]...done!
23:14:57.682 [devops] createExecTx -> DEBU 03f Creating secure invocation transaction 774fd330-ed1f-4a4d-b472-15386f3b5505
23:14:57.683 [devops] invokeOrQuery -> DEBU 040 Sending invocation transaction (774fd330-ed1f-4a4d-b472-15386f3b5505) to validator
23:14:57.683 [peer] sendTransactionsToLocalEngine -> DEBU 041 Marshalling transaction CHAINCODE_QUERY to send to local engine
23:14:57.683 [peer] sendTransactionsToLocalEngine -> DEBU 042 Sending message CHAIN_TRANSACTION with timestamp seconds:1463786097 nanos:683657855 to local engine
23:14:57.950 [chaincode] getArgsAndEnv -> DEBU 043 Executable is /opt/gopath/bin/7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568
23:14:57.950 [chaincode] launchAndWaitForRegister -> DEBU 044 **start container**: 7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568(networkid:dev,peerid:vp0)
23:14:57.950 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 045 **waiting for container**(dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568) lock
23:14:57.950 [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 046 **got container** (dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568) lock
23:14:57.950 [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 047 **Cleanup container** dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568
23:14:57.950 [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 048 **Stop container** dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568(**cannot connect to Docker endpoint**)
23:14:57.950 [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 049 **Kill container** dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568 (**cannot connect to Docker endpoint**)
23:14:57.951 [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 04a **Remove container** dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568 (cannot connect to Docker endpoint)
23:14:57.951 [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 04b **Start container** dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568
23:14:57.951 [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 04c **Create container**: dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568
23:14:57.951 [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 04d **start-could not recreate container cannot connect to Docker endpoint**
23:14:57.951 [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 04e **container lock deleted**(dev-vp0-7849b0cdbc04a8498e3601188bf4ef87d25b5efda9d89cdb879914fcbbe544a429d379bdcb210e2ba7de131ee84b53b974e3afcbacbcf0e2db4ec408a4ddb568)
23:14:57.951 [chaincode] LaunchChaincode -> DEBU 04f **launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: cannot connect to Docker endpoint**
23:14:57.951 [crypto] CloseClient -> INFO 050 Closing client [jim]...

**Question here being why is the container being taken offline aka terminated ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try 
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:30303 peer chaincode query -l golang -n   -c '{"Function": "query", "Args": ["a"]}' -u jim

Also looks like your docker container has not started correctly, do you have any errors from init on peer log

Comment: Yes, i did realize that running init command has identical logs. Using the following parameter resolved the issue                                                           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
Thanks for your help though !

Comment: Thanks! was the -v option for chaincode command or when starting peer

Comment: I'm facing similar issue, but I'm using IBM bluemix network . I get status "Ok" message on deploy and invoke, but query gives me the similar error. Any insights ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure of setting the following options for your installed docker:

```
-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```